# Entry event doesn't evaluate contacts from Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have set up a **SalesforceDataEvent** as entry event for a journey, which is now in testing mode. The entry event is set to fire, each time a Contact in Sales Cloud is either created or updated.

Even though I both create new Contact in Salesforce and update existing, I don't get any of these evaluated in the entry event. They are, however, synchronized into the Synchronized Salesforce data extensions - so no doubt about these being created.

Any clue about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please check if there are any entries for evaluated contacts int he log and add this info to your question? You can check this via "View Event Results" within your journey and then clicking on the evaluated/injected contacts link.

Comment: I wish I could do this, but the list is empty, and the number of evaluated entries is 0

Comment: Are you testing a journey in test mode? if so, try to activate the journey and run the fire event; in some cases journey not injected subscribes in test mode.

Comment: I have been testing both in test-mode, and activated the journey as well. Both without any luck

Comment: Any additional info on what the criteria is? For records being updated as an example, the field(s) has to contain something that is NOT the entry requirement, then get changed to meet the entry requirement.

Comment: The only criteria we are looking at, is a boolean value of `EmailOptOut` which needs to be `False` - but we never get that far as evaluating a single member.